# accessing div contents using .this

Tags: javascript

I am having a bit of trouble understanding `this`. I have the following piece of code that is used  on an editable div.

```
<div  onblur="myFunction(this)" class="articleFull"> Text Here </div>
```

In myFunction I am trying to grab the actual text from the div, but nothing seems to work.

I can grab the class name by using:

```
function myFunction(div) {
    alert(div.className);
}
```

Nothing seems to return the actual text inside the div. I can't seem to use `document.getElementById(...)`, as the id always changes, and `div` in this case isn't a name.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

```
function myFunction(div){
  alert(div.textContent);
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.  I think I hit the down arrow when I was trying to hit the accept answer button.... sorry.